# Regular Expression: different results with findall function

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Please explain below behaviour.

```
matches=re.findall('([^\d]{3,})|(g8 )',input_string)
for m in matches:
    print type(m)
```

gives `<type 'tuple'>`

```
matches=re.findall('([^\d]{3,})',input_string)
for m in matches:
    print type(m)
```

gives `<type 'unicode'>`

Comment: The answer is "read the [`re.findall` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall)": *Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are two capturing groups present in your first regex, `re.findall` should return a list of tuples containing exactly two elements of each. Number of items on the tuple is based upon the capturing groups (>=2).

In the second case, there is only one capturing group present so it returns a list of unicode strings.

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'fohgsdhgfo'
>>> re.findall(r'(f)|(o)', s)
[('f', ''), ('', 'o'), ('f', ''), ('', 'o')]
>>> re.findall(r'(f)', s)
['f', 'f']
```